# Making a dropdown find() faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I have a dropdown box and an input that is used to autofilter the dropdown.I need to make a dropdown filtering faster. I've added a textbox before the dropdown menu and an event to filter the dropdown:The code snippet is:

```
 td.prepend(' <span class="ms-metadata"><br/>(type some chars to filter )</span><br/>');
 .....
 td.prepend($('<input/>', {id: 'DPFilter',
                        onkeyup: 'filterDP(this)'
                         }));
```

and on the function filterDP(element) :

```
....
var value = $(element).val();
$( dropdown).find("option").each(function() {
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        $(dropdown).find('option[value="' + optionValue + '"]').map(function () {return     $(this).parent('span').length === 0 ? this : null;})
               .wrap('<span>')
         $(this).map(function () { return $(this).parent('span').length === 0 ? this : null;}).wrap('<span>').hide();
...
if ((value == "") ||  ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) ){
     $(dropdown).find('option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').show();
}
```

The only place I can think of, is the $(dropdown).find('option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').show(); , instead of finding it, to use an index, but I don't know how.

Also, I use the find() twice (in a code not shown), will a variable making faster?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can both simplify and speed this up by using `filter`:

```
var value = $(element).val();
$(dropdown).filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) != -1) {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if filter would work. Ive added some code. For every option, I first hide it and then show it.

Comment: Could you add your HTML to the question too - at least a short sample of it if there's a lot of options in the select - and also the exact behaviour you want. It's not 100% clear what you're expecting to happen from the code alone.